# Samsung s7 edge message "previous setting restored"

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow, popup

I keep getting a little notification pop up (a grey oval) that lasts about a second and says "previous settings restored" . It makes the phone vibrate and beep. It is causing annoyance and I would like to know what app/setting is causing it. I am running Android 6.0.1.

Comment: i've done some investigation and suspect this pop up is causes by the places edge panel.

Answer (score 0):

This message was caused by the 'locations' edge panel. Disabling said panel stopped the message appearances.